# Break and combine torrent file

Tags: torrent

Is there a way I can break a big torrent file (say, more than 4 GB) into small parts (say, less than 1 GB each) and download them separately ? 
I should later be able to combine them and the final result should be the same as if I had downloaded the whole torrent file in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A torrent file contains modular information about the file it's tracking as 'pieces', which are slices of the entire file you're downloading, pieces are generally between 16KB and 4MB.

So, in essence, a torrent is downloaded as n parts and combined later as it is, all you'd need is a client that would let you specify that you only want the first, second, third or fourth quarter of the pieces, which is where you'll run into some trouble, I don't know if there's any client that would support such a thing.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24520521/719276), it's possible to [split a file in smaller chunks](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=split+file&t=hc&ia=web) with a file archiver or similar software.
You can then send those files with torrents.